# Managed Routers, and Internet Connectivity Options for them

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-router, vmware

I have a home lab (just a dell server as of now) that I'm looking to upgrade with a Managed Switch and Router for 2 reasons, Inter-VLAN Routing, and Internet.

I can find affordable managed switches, but the managed routers are either wired and affordable, or wireless and expensive, and I also could not find affordable home wireless routers that can do VLAN. The house has WiFi so I'm looking to provide internet to the Managed Router via WiFi. I'm thinking of 2 things for internet to the managed router.

1. A USB Wifi Adapter (at the moment I don't know if this can provide internet to the wired router by sticking it in the USB port)
2. A Wifi Range Extender with an Ethernet port that I can connect to the Managed Router.

As I'm also looking to have Inter-VLAN routing, I had thought of connecting the Managed Switch to my laptop that has VMware Workstation that runs a OPNsense Firewall VM which can do VLANs. At the moment the laptop connects to a Dell server via a Bridged connection where the traffic from the server comes to a Firewall VM in the laptop. I'm looking to connect the server to the switch, and the switch to the laptop, just unsure if the Firewall VM in VMware Workstation will do Inter-VLAN routing this way. The port between the laptop and the Switch will be trunk.

If anyone has anything better that might work for both VLAN, and Internet..

Comment: Welcome to Superuser.  Unfortunately this is off-topic as it is a product recommendation request, so will most likely be closed.  A solution to your "cheap managed router" problem is to get a router compatible with dd-wrt and flash that onto it.  I don't know what you call affordable - and there are no doubt much cheaper options, but I have an ASUS AC-68U running dd-wrt which supports VLANS and cost me US$130.

Comment: Found https://www.amazon.com/TP-Link-AC1750-Smart-WiFi-Router/dp/B079JD7F7G/ref=psdc_300189_t3_B01N08LPPP which should also work with DD-WRT (but double check) - for less then $60.

Comment: Any router that supports [OpenWrt](https://openwrt.org/toh/views/toh_available_16128) would be better than an OEM managed switch _(OpenWrt has more features than DD-WRT)_ - you should be able to find a router capable of running OpenWrt with at least 16MB of flash and 128MB of RAM for under $100 _(OpenWrt also supports Pi's and Arduino)_. You could also run a router OS (Sophos [UTM](https://www.sophos.com/en-us/products/unified-threat-management.aspx) as a _software appliance_, [pfSense](https://www.pfsense.org/), etc.) off a server board or motherboard _(ECC RAM would be highly recommended)_

Answer (score 0):

Usually, enterprise networks don't mix routing and Wi-Fi in the first place. If you've reached the point where you need VLANs, then your router should be *just* a router, with a bunch of standalone Wi-Fi access points connected to it via Ethernet.

So yes, if you want a home lab then get a standalone router, then try connecting your "range extender" to it for Wi-Fi. You can also easily reconfigure most "wireless routers" to act as bridges / access points, in case you have some that are lacking routing features but with good Wi-Fi capabilities. This is a bit clunkier than centrally-managed access points but will still work and even allow your devices to roam from one to another.

*(For example, our main building has ~40 UniFi access points all over the place, connected to a Mikrotik router that is rack-mounted and has no Wi-Fi capability at all – it only cares about routing and DHCP for the several VLANs. In the past, the router used to be a pfSense VM running on Hyper-V.)*

However, I would probably recommend against running the router as a VM *on a laptop.* (Among other things, they aren't quite meant to run 24/7, and they also don't really have the best Ethernet interfaces.) At least make it a desktop or some kind of NUC. In fact, there are cheap microservers on eBay, usually with 2–4 Ethernet ports.

Comment: I believe that running a router as a VM on a laptop is entirely sustainable - laptops are quite capable of running 24/7 and as long as the laptop has something better then a realtek card (eg an Intel which is fairly common) there is no issues from the ethernet POV as long as you don't need multiple on-board ports.  Also, you will want to ensure the battery - if you care about it - can be kept at 60% charge, eg in BIOS. Many NUCS are essentially laptops without batteries and screens.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I won't be running it 24/7 and the laptop runs the Firewall/Router VM super fine, no issues there. The problem with standalone routers are no VLAN..

Comment: Probably every single product from Mikrotik has VLANs (and routing protocols, and IPsec, and BGP, and...) The other option is one of the EdgeRouter series.